# How to assign $.post function to a specific part of the refering file

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

```
function ajaxCheck(){ 
    var inpUs = $("#user").val(); 
    $.post(
        "./inpCheck.php",
        { user : inpUs }, 
        function(data) { // here is the point
            if (data.length > 0) { 
                $("#spanUser").html(data); 
            } 
        }
    ) 
}
```

This checks if a user already exists, and it works, but instead of `$.post("./inpCheck.php",` I want to refer to a specific part (function) of that file ?
Because, on the same file I want to write code for another inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible, what you can do is use `switch` in php, like

js part

```
$.post("./inpCheck.php", {user : inpUs, act_name : "some_function"}, function(data){
..
```

and in **inpCheck.php**

```
$action = $_POST['act_name'];
switch($action) {
  case "some_function":
     call_some_function();
  break;
}
//somewhere in same page
function call_some_function() {
  //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as i'm aware, you can't POST / GET to a specific function in a .php file directly. Instead, you need to set a method of sending to the php file, and then in the php file itself, do some logic to decide which function you want. This can be done by sending some data with the POST, perhaps a hidden field or whatever, and using this to decide which function to run. For example, in the php file;

```
if($_POST['someValue'] == "functionOne")
  {
     FunctionOne();
  }
else
  {
     FunctionTwo();
  }
```

Edit 1: For slightly relevant information, see here: [setting form action as function in external php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096733/setting-form-action-as-function-in-external-php-file)